# Knockout save height of div

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a few divs using jQuery that are resizeable.  What I want to do is assign the height of the div to a knockout property somehow so when the height is changed the value is saved in knockout model.  I thought about using the 'css' or 'attr' binding to do this, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your bindings you could use jQuery events, for example:

```
data-bind="event:{'resize':sizeChanged}"
```

I've adjusted your example.

**Please, try** [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry_zaets/z8G4k/12/)

Answer (score 0):

The css, attr bindings are not a true "two-way" binding, like when the width and height in DOM change, the model gets updated.

There is a [jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) which binds the resize event.

Listen to this event and change the properties of the model. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/z8G4k/) a fiddle.